# How to restrict the contour plot only to 3sigma variation for a 2Dimensional gaussian?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, normal-distribution

I was a bit curious on plotting the contour plots for a 2 dimensional gaussian distribution. In my case, for a given set of 2D points, I cluster them into different grid cells and compute the covariance matrix for every cell and plot the gaussian distribution for each and every cell. When I plot I do not want the entire contour for the cell but the distribution restricted within 3 sigma of the data points. Is there anyway it could be done ?

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def createCells():
    partition = 4
    coords = [np.linspace(-1.0 , 1.0, num = partition + 1) for i in range(2)]
    x, y =  np.meshgrid(*coords)
    return x, y
    
def probab(mean, covMat, lPoints):
    lPoints = lPoints[..., np.newaxis] if lPoints.ndim == 2 else lPoints  ## Create vectorized values for the x, y
    if np.linalg.det(covMat) > 0:
        factor1 = (2*np.pi)*(np.linalg.det(covMat)**(-1/2))
        factor2 = np.exp((-1/2)*np.einsum('ijk,jl,ilk->ik', lPoints - mean, np.linalg.inv(covMat), lPoints - mean))
        return factor1*factor2
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = np.array([[-0.35, -0.15], [0.1, 0.1], [-0.1, 0.1], [0.05, 0.05],[0.25, 0.05], [0.1, 0.15], [0.1, 0.2], [-0.2, -0.2], [-0.25, 0.25], [0.45, 0.45], [0.75, 0.75], [0.6, 0.6], [0.55, 0.55], [0.7, 0.7], [0.68, 0.73]])
    x1, y1 = createCells()
    x = x1[0]
    y = y1[:,0]
    lP = np.array([])
    numberOftimes = 0
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        for j in range(len(y) - 1):
            count = 0
            meanX = 0.0
            meanY = 0.0
            localPoints = []
            covMat1 = np.array([])
            covMat2 = np.array([])
            for point in points:
                inbetween_x = x[i] <= point[0] <= x[i + 1]
                inbetween_y = y[j] <= point[1] <= y[j + 1]
                if inbetween_x and inbetween_y:
                    count += 1
                    meanX += point[0]
                    meanY += point[1]
                    localPoints.append([point[0], point[1]])
            if count >= 2:
                numberOftimes += 1
                #print(f"The local points are {localPoints}")
                localPoints = np.array(localPoints)
                meanX /= count
                meanY /= count
                meanXY = np.array([meanX, meanY])
                #print(meanXY.shape)
                #print(localPoints.shape)
                lP = localPoints - meanXY
                for k in range(count):
                    lPtranspose = (np.array([lP[k]])).T
                    lPCurrent = (np.array([lP[k]]))
                    if len(covMat1) > 0:
                        covMat1 += lPtranspose.dot(lPCurrent)
                    else:
                        covMat1 = lPtranspose*lP[k]
                        covMat1 /= count
                lPoints = localPoints[..., np.newaxis] if lP.ndim == 2 else lP  ## Create vectorized values for the x, y
                meanXY1 = localPoints.mean(0)
                meanXY2 = lPoints.mean(0)
                covMat3 = np.einsum('ijk, ikj->jk', lPoints - meanXY2, lPoints - meanXY2) / lPoints[0] - 1
                #yamlStatus = self.savingYaml(i, j, meanXY, covMat3) ## To store the cell parameters in a yaml file (for now its just out of scope for the question)
                if np.linalg.det(covMat3) > 0:   #compute the probability only if the det is not 0
                    Xx = np.linspace(x[i], x[i + 1], 1000)
                    Yy = np.linspace(y[i], y[i + 1], 1000)
                    Xx,Yy = np.meshgrid(Xx, Yy)
                    lPoints = np.vstack((Xx.flatten(), Yy.flatten())).T
                    pos = np.empty(Xx.shape + (2,))
                    pos[:, :, 0] = Xx
                    pos[:, :, 1] = Yy
                    z2 = probab(meanXY2, covMat3, lPoints)
                    summed = np.sum(z2)
                    z2 = z2.reshape(1000, 1000)
                    cs = plt.contourf(Xx, Yy, z2)#, cmap=cm.viridis)
                    plt.clabel(cs)
                localPoints = []
                #print(f"The number of times count is greater than 1 is {numberOftimes}")
        plt.plot(x1, y1, marker='.', linestyle='none', markersize=20)
        plt.plot(points[:,0 ], points[:, 1], marker='.', linestyle='none', markersize=10)
        plt.grid(linewidth=0.5)#abs(x1[0][0]-y1[0][0]))
        plt.show()
```

Comment: please modify your code to make it run, then others can help you

Comment: @ted Thank you for looking into it and the suggestion. I have edited. Hoping to get some replies

Comment: what you showed is only part of your class, I don't think it is runnable by others. Make your code minimum and runnable, then other guys will spend less time making it work. If the code cannot run, most people will just ignore your question....

Comment: @ted930511, thanks again for your valuble suggestion, kinda getting the hang of being in stackoverflow. I have make the code as a standalone piece, so now it should be fine to run. Hoping to get some insights and clues..

Comment: I guess what you need is to do a 2d gaussian fitting? What is your expected result (if there are any similar plots)? Output from your code looks strange to me...

Comment: @ted930511, thanks again for looking into the problem. There was an intendentation error which I corrected with the last edit. So my expectation and requirements are 1) I should be able to capture the shape of the points within each and every cell of the plot. The points are basically (x, y) so when I plot a gaussian distribution I get an ellipsoidal shape in the 3D, but I would want that projected as a 2D contour on the plot (x, y) describing the density of the points in ellipses. By this way I will be able to understand the shape of the points which are captured in the 2D grid.

Comment: There is a restriction on count of the points for a particular cell (count >= 2) because if there is just one point, there is no shape information..